# How to update multiple properties of a nested object inside an array in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Let say we have a document in mongodb

```js
{
  id : 101,
  addresses : [
    {
      id: 1,
      suite: "flat 201",
      street: "north street"
      city: "london",
      country: "uk"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to update multiple properties of the object at once without replacing whole object.
For example :

```js
const newAddress = {
  id:1,
  suite: "flat 301",
  street: "south street"
} 


userCollection.updateOne(
  {id : 101},
  { $set : {"addresses.$[address]" : newAddress } },
  {arrayFilters: [{address.id : newAddress.id}]}
)
```

This operation sets the object with new fields instead of updating only the given fields.

Comment: you need to specify all properties name, `"addresses.$[address].suite" : newAddress.suite,  "addresses.$[address].street" : newAddress.street`.

Comment: what if we have many many fields.. and we can't pre define which fields user will update.

Comment: you have to prepare that logic on the client side, but the update query requires separate properties otherwise it will replace the whole object.

Comment: @turivishal ok.. looks like we have to perform a loop for each field

Comment: yes, loop that object's properties and prepare the object that the update query requires.

Comment: try this ```userCollection.updateOne({ id: 101, 'addresses.id': 1 }, { $set: { 'addresses.$': newAddress } })```

Comment: will query `{id:101, 'addresses.id':1  }` be efficient than `{'addresses.id' : 1}`? will it scan only 1 document like `{id:1}` ?

Comment: @bogdanoff no it didn't work.. it replace the whole object

Comment: @FishLegs if you want to update specific fields then do it like this `userCollection.updateOne({ id: 101, 'addresses.id': 1 }, { $set: { 'addresses.$.city': newAddress.city,   'addresses.$.id: newAddress.id,  } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update an object's properties, it must be required to specify each one by one, and if the properties are dynamic then you have to prepare a payload for an update on client side,

I assume you are using javascript,

```js
const newAddress = {
  id:1,
  suite: "flat 301",
  street: "south street"
};

let set = {};
for (let n in newAddress) {
  set["addresses.$[address]."+n] = newAddress[n];
}

console.log(set);
```

> ```
> // prepared update object
> {
>  "addresses.$[address].id": 1,
>  "addresses.$[address].suite": "flat 301",
>  "addresses.$[address].street": "south street"
> }
> ```

You can pass `set` to update part in query,

```
userCollection.updateOne(
  { id : 101 },
  { $set : set },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "address.id" : newAddress.id }] }
)
```

---

You can do this directly in an update query but you have to use an [update with an aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) and I don't recommend this because it requires multiple expression operators and it is expensive.

Comment: should i select nested array's object using `arrayFilters` or multiple query operator like `({id:1, "address.id": newAddress.id})`. what will scan less docs to find it?

Comment: yes you can filter nested array's object by `arrayFilters`.

Comment: i know i can use arrayFilters.. but which way is more efficient between arrayFilters and multiple query parameter?

Comment: i am not exactly getting what is *multiple query parameter*?

Comment: can i use query like `const query = { id:101, 'address.id: 1 }` instead of arrayFilters? will this query will be equally efficient to select target object as arrayFilters?

Comment: yes you can use that but it will update only single element in arrray, so if you know the `id` is unique then you can use that, if `id` is not unique and you want to update multiple elements then you can use arrayFilters.

Comment: yes i want to update single element in array and id is unique for each element.

Comment: then yes you can use that using `$` positional update, no need to use arrayFilters.